# Applying for computer science internships, using email with .dev ending

Tags: software-industry, resume, internship

Google Domains recently released the `.dev` domain extension and I was able to register `jdoe.dev` (example).

Would putting `john@jdoe.dev` on a resume be a bad idea or potentially too confusing? My fear is that someone might not recognize it as an e-mail address because of the unusual extension.

Should I just stick with GMail?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what kind of positions you will be applying to with this address on your resume?

Comment: @jesse Software Engineer Intern

Comment: I'd say **it's confusing / oddball**.   One person's vote, don't do it.  With things like your CV, just stick to absolutely standard practice.

Comment: "My fear is that someone might not recognize it as an e-mail address because of the unusual extension." - I think it's not hard to recognize an email address. Not sure what's so confusing about it.

Answer (score 3):

I personnaly think it should be fine.
There is plenty of weird domain out there, and any company wich is even remotely computer savy probably won't be phased by wich domain you're using.

But Some domain do appear less professional than others. I have seen many people scoff at a freelancer using `@gmail` as a domain instead of a domain of their own.

I also tend to think that most company will try to contact you by phone instead of mail. At least in my experience almost every first contact I've had with a company was by phone call, with subsequent contact being by mail.

Long story short, I don't think that using the `.dev` domain will harm your resume, or credibility, or at least not damage it enough for your application to be rejected only for that. As long as you have at least one other way to contact you, it should all go fine.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think people will be confused by this kind of address but it won't bring you more contacts by potential employers as it is either. Only some domains have an frivolous reputation, and *yourname.dev* is not one of them, neither is *gmail.com*

You said that you registered a `.dev` domain. Do you have any website also associated with this domain ? **It could be a plus if you have a cool website presenting your work and capabilities AND a contact address associated with it**. It works as an ensemble and could make a whole, coherent portrait of your skills.

It could event hit your targets with an original touch if they pay attention !